# Test Trigger code on Campaign Member

Tags: class

I have a relatively simple trigger that changes a date on the Contact record based on a change to the Status Value in the CampaignMember record. The trigger seems to work. Excuse all the .debugs, I learn by watching the results. (I have looked at as many answers as I can find to this question.)

Here is the trigger, please pardon the blank lines:

```
trigger UpdateContact on CampaignMember (after update, after insert) {
    // Get a list of all the contact IDs to be updated
    System.debug('begin mycode debugs');
    System.debug(Trigger.Old);
    System.debug(Trigger.New);

    // First section pulls the list of IDs from the trigger if the member status is Completed

    List<ID> Contacts2Update = new List<ID>();

    for(CampaignMember m : Trigger.New) {                // Build a list of Contact IDs for query
        system.debug(m.ContactID);  
        if (m.Status == 'Completed'){
            Contacts2Update.add(m.ContactID);
        }
    } 
    System.debug('Contact ID List' + Contacts2Update );     // How big is the list and what's in it
    System.debug('ID List Size ' + Contacts2Update.size() ); 

    // Second section creats a list of contact records to be modified if the above list is not empty

    List<Contact> contacts;                                 // Must happen here to prevent a compile error

    if (Contacts2Update.size() > 0){                // Final Processing, pull contact records, update the field, Update the records
                                                            // This builds a list of Contact Records based on IDs from above
        contacts = [select id, firstname, lastname, email, Last_Completed_Member_Action__c from Contact where id in:Contacts2Update];
        System.debug('contacts List ' + contacts);     // How big is the list and what's in it
        System.debug('contact List Size ' + contacts.size() ); 

         if (contacts.size() > 0) {                           // changes the completed action date for each record  
             for(Integer i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++) {
                 contacts[i].Last_Completed_Member_Action__c = system.today();
             }
             update contacts;                                  // update all the records in the list
          }
      }
}
```

I wrote a test class for this code that does not work. (I don't understand how test classes and trigger code connect.) Here it is (some was lifted from something Thomas Taylor, one of my heroes, posted:

```
@isTest
private class CampaignMemberInsertTest {
   private static testMethod void testUpdateCM() {
    //create & insert test data 
    //make sure to include all required fields and that it will pass any active Validation Rules

    system.debug('Started Member Insert Test Class');

    Test.startTest();
    Account acct = new Account (Name = 'Acme, Inc.');
    insert acct;
    system.debug('Inserted Account, ID: ' + acct.id);

    Contact con = new Contact(
                      FirstName = 'Robin',
                      LastName = 'Koehler',
                      AccountId = acct.Id
                      );
    insert con;   
    system.debug('Inserted Contact, ID: ' + con.id);

    Campaign camp = new Campaign(
                        Name = 'Test',
                        IsActive = TRUE
                        );            
    insert camp;
    system.debug('Inserted Campaign, ID: ' + camp.id);

    CampaignMember member = new CampaignMember(
        ContactId = con.Id,
        Status = 'Completed',
        CampaignId = camp.Id
        ); 
    insert member; 
    system.debug('Inserted CampaignMember, ID: ' + member.Id);
    system.debug('CampaignMember Status: ' + member.Status);

    system.debug('This should fire the Trigger');
Test.stopTest();           

    //Assert that data is as we expect it after trigger has run
    List<Contact> ChgContact = [Select Id, Last_Completed_Member_Action__c 
        FROM Contact
        WHERE Id = :con.Id];
    System.Debug (ChgContact[0].Last_Completed_Member_Action__c );
    System.Debug (System.Today());
    System.Debug (ChgContact[0].Id);


    System.assertEquals(System.Today(),ChgContact[0].Last_Completed_Member_Action__c );
    }
```

}

This does not do what I expect. That is, nothing is verified.

The trigger itself works. I can verify that by changing status values on the CampaignMember and then looking at the Contact Record. I'm happy to read any references that might help me.

Thanks... Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite simple:

You have in your testmethod:

```
CampaignMember member = new CampaignMember(
        ContactId = con.Id,
        Status = 'Completed',
        CampaignId = camp.Id
        );
```

but ...you never insert `member` -- doing DML in the testmethod is what causes the trigger on `CampaignMember` to execute.

As an aside, since your trigger is both an `after insert` and an `after update` trigger; you'll want to extend your testmethod to include update use cases

Comment: Thanks for your help. Good catch. And I agree that I should extend the use case to Update. I'm so new at this I'm just trying to get anything to work.

Comment: np, we're here to help

Comment: Didn't mean for this to be two comments. But hitting enter does that...
After adding the Insert for the member the trigger still does not fire. The first active .debug in the trigger is 
  System.debug('begin Trigger debugs');

Comment: I did it again. An ingrained habit.
In the Developer log this never shows up so the trigger is never entered as far as I can tell.
Do I need any of the code that I've seen in some examples like:
    static testMethod void testWithDoesntExistingContact() {
Thanks for any help...Bob

Comment: Bob - (1) Please edit your original question (use Edit button) to show revised code; (2) in the debug log you should see a DML_BEGIN line for CampaignMember

Comment: I'm having trouble editing the Test code, part of it insists on staying outside the code box. So, here it is separately:
@isTest private class CampaignMemberInsertTest { private static testMethod void testUpdateCM() { //create & insert test data //make sure to include all required fields and that it will pass any active Validation Rules

Comment: join me in Chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/38255/question-117338?tab=general

Comment: I went to the chat room but did not see where I could say anything. I saw something that said I needed a score of 20. Is that the problem?
Thanks... Bob

Comment: aargh; that is correct

Comment: I found "DML_BEGIN line for CampaignMember" in the debug log, what else should I look for?

Comment: so, this means you should see (if the insert succeeded) that the after insert trigger will execute. if the insert failed, there will be an error

Comment: I extracted the log to a text file so I could search it. Found the DML_Begin for CampaignMember. There was no DML_END after it. I assume this means it failed and that's why the trigger did not execute?
I don't see anything that indicates failure but I'm a novice at this.
What should I look for?
Thanks for your patience with me... Bob

Comment: depends on your log levels, but either a) you have a failing validation rule, b) a missing required field, or c) you have somewhere else in your org a before insert trigger on CampaignMember that is failing

Comment: Interesting. In the exported log I do see the Debugs from the trigger which I did not see when filtering in the Developer Console.
I do see other actions from the NonProfitStarterPack.
Thanks for your help. I'm going to try some other stuff tomorrow including doing this with real data; it's in a sandbox. Will let you know what I find.

Comment: One other thing: I created a second test using real data for account, contact, and campaign. Inserted the Campaign Member and the test ran successfully. Go figure.

Comment: When I broke the test code into two classes, one for update and one for insert, both ran and I got 100% coverage. I used real data in the sandbox to do this.
I will tell you, quite honestly, that I don't understand a lot of this but I'm quite willing to learn.
This is my first experience with posting to StackExchange but over the past few years I've gotten quite a lot of help from posted answers.
THANKS... Bob

Comment: as a courtesy to the community, if you felt this answer assisted you; mark it as the solution

Comment: The answer was helpful. And it was very useful to have cropredy discuss it with me. I'm not clear on how to mark it as the solution.

Comment: There were a number of other problems with what I was doing but the main culprit was that the Campaign that I built in the test class would not have the MemberStatus of "completed" therefore nothing ever happened.
I really appreciate the time spent with me on this. I've gotten a lot of answers from this forum in the past few years but this is the first time I've asked a question. (I think) ...Bob

Comment: bob - just click the checkbox next to any answer to a question you posed